# MySQL Error 150: two VARCHAR(255) attributes

Tags: mysql

I am creating new tables for a archive and I am also setting foreign keys alongside of that.

I tried different kind of varchar sizes, checked InnoDB and such and checked if I made spelling errors in the table names.

```
CREATE TABLE `VKST_Project`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `brand` varchar(255),
  `city` varchar(255),
  `street` varchar(255),
  `plz` varchar(255),
  `center_name` varchar(255),
  `nation` varchar(255),
  `shop_type` varchar(255),
  `state` varchar(255),
  `sales_area` varchar(255),
  `open_date` varchar(255),
  `construction_date` varchar(255),
  `re_open_date` varchar(255),
  `local_manager` varchar(255),
  `window_length` double,
  `object_front_length` double,
  `security_alarm` boolean,
  `security_goods` boolean,
  `fire_sprinklers` boolean,
  `fire_smoke_alarm` boolean,
  `fire_RWA` boolean,
  `advert_modules` varchar(255),
  `tech_equipment` varchar(255),
  `ventilation` varchar(255),
  `heating` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;;

CREATE TABLE `Floor`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `floor_id` varchar(255),
  `object_id` int,
  `floor_space_total` double,
  `floor_space_sales` double,
  `floor_space_store` double,
  `floor_space_others` double,
  `floor_capacity_total` double,
  `floor_capacity_sales` double,
  `floor_capacity_store` double,
  `floor_capacity_others` double
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;;

CREATE TABLE `Room`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(255),
  `floor_id` varchar(255),
  `object_id` int,
  `name` varchar(255),
  `space` double,
  `height` double,
  `sap` varchar(255),
  `cad_file_name` varchar(255),
  `DIN_Type` varchar(255),
  `GIF_Type` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;;

CREATE TABLE `Ceiling`
(
  `ceiling_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(255),
  `material` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;;

CREATE TABLE `Flooring`
(
  `flooring_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(255),
  `material` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;;

ALTER TABLE `Floor` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`object_id`) REFERENCES `VKST_Project` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `Room` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`floor_id`) REFERENCES `Floor` (`floor_id`);

ALTER TABLE `Room` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`object_id`) REFERENCES `VKST_Project` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `Ceiling` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `Room` (`room_id`);

ALTER TABLE `Flooring` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`room_id`) REFERENCES `Room` (`room_id`);
```

The Error happens here: ALTER TABLE `Room` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`floor_id`) REFERENCES `Floor` (`floor_id`);

Error: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

Comment: What have you tried to debug this error? What about reducing the SQL statements to the minimal parts that trigger the error?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Why does the Error 150 happen? The key attributes are identical, InnoDB is set... If I change the floor_id of Room and of Floor to int it works.... But I should be able to make varchar foreign keys.

Comment: You have a lot of ;; in your code is that a typo?

Comment: Checked that. Removed ";" and left only 1 and same error still happens.... Also, I even pointed out where the error happens (see at the end of the post). Which is beyond the ";;".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys' mysql will generate indexes in the referencing table but YOU have to generate them in the referenced tables (floor,room) either as part of the definition or with an alter table. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

```
drop table if exists flooring;
drop table if exists ceiling;
drop table if exists room;
drop table if exists floor;
drop table if exists vkst_project;

CREATE TABLE `VKST_Project`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY,
  `brand` varchar(255),
  `city` varchar(255),
  `street` varchar(255),
  `plz` varchar(255),
  `center_name` varchar(255),
  `nation` varchar(255),
  `shop_type` varchar(255),
  `state` varchar(255),
  `sales_area` varchar(255),
  `open_date` varchar(255),
  `construction_date` varchar(255),
  `re_open_date` varchar(255),
  `local_manager` varchar(255),
  `window_length` double,
  `object_front_length` double,
  `security_alarm` boolean,
  `security_goods` boolean,
  `fire_sprinklers` boolean,
  `fire_smoke_alarm` boolean,
  `fire_RWA` boolean,
  `advert_modules` varchar(255),
  `tech_equipment` varchar(255),
  `ventilation` varchar(255),
  `heating` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Floor`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `floor_id` varchar(255),
  `object_id` int,
  `floor_space_total` double,
  `floor_space_sales` double,
  `floor_space_store` double,
  `floor_space_others` double,
  `floor_capacity_total` double,
  `floor_capacity_sales` double,
  `floor_capacity_store` double,
  `floor_capacity_others` double,
  key flk1(floor_id)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Room`
(
  `id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(255),
  `floor_id` varchar(255),
  `object_id` int,
  `name` varchar(255),
  `space` double,
  `height` double,
  `sap` varchar(255),
  `cad_file_name` varchar(255),
  `DIN_Type` varchar(255),
  `GIF_Type` varchar(255),
  key rki(room_id),
  key rk2(floor_id)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Ceiling`
(
  `ceiling_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(255),
  `material` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `Flooring`
(
  `flooring_id` int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_id` varchar(255),
  `material` varchar(255)
)  ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `Floor` ADD FOREIGN KEY fk1(`object_id`) REFERENCES `VKST_Project` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `Room` ADD FOREIGN KEY fk2(`floor_id`) REFERENCES `Floor` (`floor_id`);

ALTER TABLE `Room` ADD FOREIGN KEY fk3(`object_id`) REFERENCES `VKST_Project` (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `Ceiling` ADD FOREIGN KEY fk4(`room_id`) REFERENCES `Room` (`room_id`);

ALTER TABLE `Flooring` ADD FOREIGN KEY fk5(`room_id`) REFERENCES `Room` (`room_id`);
```

Comment: Did you scroll down in the code? I used ALTER TABLE there. I don't get what is unclear here? I am trying to add a foreign key and it produces error 150 on a foreign key where I reference varchar(255) with varchar(255). If I change that to int, error doesn't happen.

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer - you need to add KEYs to to the relevant columns in floor and room In this case I have added to the create statement. I have added amended error free code to the answer.I suggest you give the KEYs names more suited to your environment.

Comment: Ah OK. I understand :) I tested it. Thanks a lot man. It worked.